# Deploy Hooks in Liferay and JBoss

Tags: jboss, liferay, hook, liferay-hook

I need to create a Hook to inject Javascript in a site. I have not had troubles creating hook but when I deploy it, my hook is not registered like Hook.

I have tried to deploy it with Liferay and Tomcat and this work fine.

Anybody knows what could be happenning?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that Liferay's hook mechanism doesn't fully work in JBoss domain mode. The Liferay documentation says:

> "...since Liferay’s JSP override mechanism relies on the application
>   server reloading customized JSP files from the exploded plugin .war
>   file location. Other plugins, such as service or action hooks, should
>   still work properly since they don’t require JBoss to access anything
>   (such as JSP files) from an exploded .war file on the file system..."

I suggest, if you can, to change to JBoss standalone mode or change to other application server like Tomcat that is fully supported by Liferay.

You can read more information about that in [installing-liferay-on-jboss](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/6-2/installing-liferay-on-jboss-7-1)